# Breeze->EF6 updating some changed columns, but not all

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, breeze

I've got a Breeze Context Provider talking to a EF 6.1.1, database-first, application with SQL Server that I'm having some trouble with.  I can INSERT a new record, but when I update it, not all the changed columns get written to the database.

I have a generated POCO that looks like this:

```
public partial class Inventory
{
    public Inventory()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EnteredAt { get; set; }
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

When I go and update an entity on client side (setting Comment property) and send it to Breeze, I do some very simple sets in a EFContextProvider::BeforeSaveEntity override:

```
    protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
        // only one inventory is ever sent in
        if (saveMap.ContainsKey(typeof(Inventory)))
        {
            var source = saveMap[typeof(Inventory)].First().Entity as Inventory;

            // set up the user and time fields
            if (source.Id <= 0)
            {
                source.EnteredBy = _defaultUserName;
                source.EnteredAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                source.UpdatedBy = _defaultUserName;
                source.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }

         }
     }
```

But when the change gets committed, the changed UpdatedBy value never gets in to the database.

I turned on EF6 SQL logging and sure enough, the UPDATE statement completely misses the property.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Inventory]
SET [Comment] = @0, [UpdatedAt] = @1
WHERE ([Id] = @2)
-- @0: '1532' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 250)
-- @1: '2/4/2016 10:32:58 PM' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @2: '100344' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 2/4/2016 3:33:06 PM -07:00
-- Completed in 7 ms with result: 1
```

Of course, UpdatedBy is NULL in the database for this update.

I can't figure out why this particular column will not do through when an 'adjacent' column, set at the same time, does.  I also don't know if this is a Breeze problem or an EF problem since I can go back in and just using EF,  DBContext all works fine.

I also tried deleting the table from the EDMX file and re-adding it to no avail.  I re-verified that the column is in the table in the EDMX file.

As a hack, what I have to do is go back in, re-read the changed record directly, update it, then send it back.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just update the "UpdateBy" column (comment other column) and tell us what's the current state of your entity and what happen when you try to save it? "var state = ctx.Entry(source).State;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the BeforeSaveEntity method and a sample manipulation of the entity on the client side into your question?

Secondly, make sure you're updating the propertyMap for the entity info in your BeforeSave method like so:

```
source.UpdatedBy = "Joe User";
source.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
source.Comment = "1532";

entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap["UpdatedBy"] = null;
entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap["UpdatedAt"] = null;
entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap["Comment"] = null;
```

I'm wondering if the "UpdatedAt" property is manipulated on the client before calling saveChanges, and therefore this property would already by identified as 'Modified' in the property map.

Answer (score 0):

please Refer this Question you will get answer.

[how to secure add or delete entities with breezejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621718/how-to-secure-add-or-delete-entities-with-breezejs/31696658#31696658)

Two option here : 
1. change in actual saveMap entity not in new entity.
2. create new entity as 'source' and replace it with actual entity.